# What is 'CDF1' in this Summary-Level formula Column in Salesforce.com --> (CDF1:SUM)/RowCount

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have to migrate a Report with this Summary-Level formula Column from one Org to another:

**(CDF1:SUM)/RowCount**

I am trying to reproduce this same Summary-Level formula column in the target Org/report but I do not know what the 'CDF1' is.

CDF1 seems to me like a api field automatically generated by Salesforce.com (?) but... I have no clue.

Any idea or hint that can help me migrate/reproduce the same formula in the target Org?

Thank you.

Comment: I am now migrating another report containing another Summary-Level Formula column which inclused this formula: CDF1:UNIQUE ; again, what is CDF1 ?

Comment: How can I know what is CDF1 representing?

Answer (score 0):

The "CDF1" represent a custom column created previously as a "Row-Level Formula Column".

CDF1 has been created by Salesforce when the above mentioned "Row-Level Formula Column" was created on the same Report.